# Programmatically cropping an array along all its axes in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I want to (uniformly) reduce the dimensions of a numpy array (matrix) in each direction. The code below works.

```
array = np.array([3, 2323, 212, 2321, 54])
padding = 1
array[padding:-padding]
```

**Output**:

```
[2323, 12, 2321]
```

But I want this to be done another way. My array will be 50-dimensional and I want to apply the last line to each dimension of the array, but I don't want to write much code.

Maybe something like

```
  array[padding: -padding for i in range(50)]
```

But it doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can produce the relevant [`slice`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=slice#slice)s directly;

```
array[array.ndim * [slice(1, -1)]]
```

For instance,

```
In [31]: array = np.zeros((3, 4, 5, 6))

In [32]: array[array.ndim * [slice(1, -1)]].shape
Out[32]: (1, 2, 3, 4)
```

Comment: Great. If you found the answer helpful, you can [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).